# How do I stop my IF statements from conflicting and how do I choose which one has priority?

Tags: php, date, if-statement

I'm quite new to PHP and I've been asked to write a script that displays an image based on time. I've deducted that I need to use PHP's native 'date' function for this and up until I was asked to implement bank holidays and Christmas into it, all went well.

I tried to add the Christmas and bank holidays in as a separate if statement but that was when disaster struck and I haven't been able to figure out why it's come to a halt. I've tried using an online PHP validator to no avail.

Please don't be afraid to throw details and jargon at me as I really wish to expand my knowledge of PHP and rely less on the support of web forums in the future!

Here is the code:

```
<?php

        // Date-time (day of month, month) 

        $d = date('j'); // Day of month: Numeric without leading zeroes
        $m = date('n'); // Month: As above
        $D = date('w'); // Day of week
        $H = date('G'); // Hour of day

        // REGULAR OPENING TIMES
        // Closed before 9am on weekdays
        if ($H < 9 && $D <= 5) :
                $showroom_img = '/media/gbu0/pagehead/showroom_closed.jpg';
        // Open before 5pm (but after 9, as first if statement overrides this) on weekdays
        elseif ($H < 17 && $D <= 5) :
                $showroom_img = = '/media/gbu0/pagehead/showroom_open.jpg';
        // Closed before 10am on Saturdays
        elseif ($H < 10 && $D == 6) :
                $showroom_img = = '/media/gbu0/pagehead/showroom_closed.jpg';
        // Open between 10am and 2pm on Saturdays
        elseif ($H < 14 && $H > 10 && $D == 6) :
                $showroom_img = = '/media/gbu0/pagehead/showroom_open.jpg';
        // Any other time, display closed image :)
        else :
                $showroom_img = = '/media/gbu0/pagehead/showroom_closed.jpg';
        endif;

        // Holidays 2014

        $xmas_starts = ($d == 23 && $m == 12 && $d > 17);
        $xmas_ends   = ($d == 26 && $m == 12);
        $nyd         = ($d == 1 && $m = 1);

        // Easter Friday: April 18
        // Easter Monday: April 21
        // Early Spring B/H: May 5
        // Late Spring B/H: May 26
        // Summer B/H: August 25

        // All bank holidays: 10am - 2pm

        if( date >= $xmas_starts && $day <= $xmas_ends ) :
                $xmas = true;
        elseif( date = $nyd ) :
                $nyd = true;
        else :
                $bankhol = false;
        endif;

        if( $xmas = true ) :
                $showroom_img = "/media/gbu0/pagehead/showroom_xmas.jpg";
        elseif( $bankhol = true && date('F', 'j') = strpos('April 18' || 'April 21' || 'May 5' || 'May 26' || 'August 25') || date('w') = 6 ) :
                $showroom_img = "/media/gbu0/pagehead/showroom_bhol.jpg";
        elseif( date('w') = 7 ) :
                $showroom_img = "/media/gbu0/pagehead/showroom_closed.jpg";
        else :
                $showroom_img = "/media/gbu0/pagehead/showroom_open.jpg";
        endif;

?>
```

Comment: `if ( $xmas = true )` - this will always be true; a single `=` assigns a value. If you want to compare, then you need `==`

Comment: By applying logical - this applies as a principal to programming.

Comment: What I'm trying to say with that statement is that `if $xmas` is set as `true` as assigned by the previous statement (where the value of `$xmas` is set depending on whether the server time is between two dates) then to set the main variable as the Xmas image, else use the bank holiday image, or closed, or so on.

Do I need to specify if `$xmas` is not true then to ignore it and focus on the other variables in the `elseif`s following it?

Comment: Just use if ($xmas) instead.

Comment: '=' is assignation, '==' is logical operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all. I noticed a couple of bugs :

```
elseif( date = $nyd ) :
                $nyd = true;
```

and

```
if( $xmas = true ) :
                $showroom_img = "/media/gbu0/pagehead/showroom_xmas.jpg";
```

In PHP, '=' is the assignment operator, used to assign value to a variable. What you need here is the comparison operator, '=='. For example :

```
if( $xmas == true ) :
```

Or you could also do (it's pointed out in a comment already) :

```
if( $xmas ) :
```

Rgarding priority, the if statements are going to be checked in the order you write them in your code. TO ensure that a condition gets the highest priority, that has to be checked first.

Comment: In fact `if($a == true)` could very well be `if($a)`, considering that `==` is not a strict equality it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: From what I understand: `if($a)` checks whether it's true or false automatically, and if true "activates" the condition / line after it? (sorry if this is confusing, I'm still learning the jargon.)

Comment: yes you can consider it as "activates", but in proper programming terms, it's referred to as "execution". When the condition is satisfied, the statements inside that conditional block are executed. Otherwise, the next statement is executed, and so on. The next statement can be another conditional statement, or assignment etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the switch case function instead of elseif?

Switch case method:

```
switch ($i) {
case 0:
    echo "i equals 0";
    break;
case 1:
    echo "i equals 1";
    break;
case 2:
    echo "i equals 2";
    break;
}
```

Read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: I don't think a `switch` would be useful here, as the conditions are too complex.

Comment: I assume the benefits of this would be that everything would be in one statement instead of several statements to determine the value of particular variables? I've heard it's better optimised than if statements that have a lot of different conditions but I've not looked into it. I will now though :)

Answer (score 0):

`if` statements cannot conflict, and have no concept of priority. Each one is evaluated and executed in the order it appears, unless it gets skipped by code branching (e.g. an `elseif` would get skipped if a previous `if` or `elseif` in the same chain evaluated to true).

The cause of your problems is most likely your confusion of assignment and equality operators (`=` and `==`).

In all situations, `x = y` is an assignment; i.e. it assigns the value of `y` to the variable `x`. This is the case even if you put it in an `if` statement, so it's usually something you want to avoid (although there are situations where it's useful).

In all situations, `x == y` is an equality comparison; i.e. it checks if the value of `x` is (or can be converted to) the same as the value of `y`. This is the one you usually want in an `if` condition.

To put it another way, you want to change this:

```
if( $xmas = true )
```

To this:

```
if( $xmas == true )
```

You'll need to do the same thing in a couple of other places as well.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! I figured something was up with the operator but I wasn't sure what.